# What determines whether web.debug.config or web.release.config are used

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I am new to Visual Studio and want to get a grip on publishing a web project.

(I have a fair understanding of how to use Web Deploy publish profiles created by IIS but I don't think the config files are directly related to pubxml files. I also understand the principle of transforms within the web.debug.config and web.release.config files but of course any additional information to the questions below are welcome.)

In VS 2013 to the right of Browser Link is the Solution Configurations drop-down containing Debug/Release/Configuration Manager...

1. When publishing to production (forget about staging, azure etc, just a simple publish to IIS) do I select Release which in turn will use web.release.config?
2. In Configuration Manager... there is a Deploy column with a check box. Mine is disabled. What is that about?

Comment: It's based on the release configuration. However you can create transforms for your pubxml as well.

Comment: dman2306
Sorry but your answer is too vague for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to summarize what you have to do in few points but, please follow the publish guide here:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis

1. Create the publish profile
2. Configure deployment for the membership database
3. Configure publish profile transforms
4. Preview your deployment and publish.

I hope that answer your 1st question.

As for the 2nd question, it is disabled because you have not defined your publishing profile, do the what described above and it will be enabled.

Let me know if you need anymore information or if I my answer solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you DeJaVo for assisting me publish.
1. I have created the  publish profile and validated the connection.
2. I have no DB to deploy.
3. IMPORTANT! are you saying that these transforms affect the web.release/test/whatever.config files OR are they unrelated?
4. I have published many times over the last few months.

I'm not sure my Q is understood.
"1.When publishing to production (forget about staging, azure etc, just a simple publish to IIS) do I select Release which in turn will use web.release.config?"
If it is not clear please ask.

Comment: According to the link I've added the answer to issue #3 is Yes - they are related. issue #4 - after configuration is defined , clicking release will use we.release.config which was defined by you in the publish profile.

Comment: Thank you DeJaVo once again. I will do a few examples and see what happens.